# How to access files of a specific file extension from a cell array on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, cell-array, file-extension

I'm trying to access all of the files with a certain file extension from a cell array I have created on MATLAB, but I'm unsure how to do this. Furthermore, I need to be able to make this a variable input. ie so that when I call my function, I can input different file extensions to access different files which correspond to the inputted file extension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you provide an example, together with the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) to find the extension of interest within your filename, put that inside an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to let this anonymous function work on each of your cell array elements.

Please have a look at the following code snippet:

```matlab
% Files cell array
files = {
  'text1.txt',
  'text2.txt',
  'image1.png',
  'image2.jpg',
  'audio1.mp3',
  'audio2.mp3'
}

% Extension of interest
ext = 'txt';

% Use strfind operation in cellfun
temp = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(strfind(x, ['.' ext])), files, 'UniformOutput', false)

% Combine outputs, and find proper indices
idx = find([temp{:}])

% Get files with extension of interest
filesExt = files(idx)

% Get files with extension of interest as one-liner 
% (for the Octave users, where the syntactic sugar for {:} is available)
filesExt = files(find([cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(strfind(x, ['.' ext])), files, 'UniformOutput', false){:}]))
```

And, this is the output:

```matlab
files =
{
  [1,1] = text1.txt
  [2,1] = text2.txt
  [3,1] = image1.png
  [4,1] = image2.jpg
  [5,1] = audio1.mp3
  [6,1] = audio2.mp3
}

temp =
{
  [1,1] = 1
  [2,1] = 1
  [3,1] = 0
  [4,1] = 0
  [5,1] = 0
  [6,1] = 0
}

idx =
   1   2

filesExt =
{
  [1,1] = text1.txt
  [2,1] = text2.txt
}

filesExt =
{
  [1,1] = text1.txt
  [2,1] = text2.txt
}
```

Since I'm currently on Octave, I can't guarantee the one-liner to work on MATLAB. Maybe, someone can please confirm. Anyway, the step-by-step solution should work as intended.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** As [Wolfie points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819094/11089932), "double file extensions" like `x.txt.png` might cause trouble using this approach.

Comment: The one-liner isn't MATLAB compatible, you need the intermediate variable for the `{:}` operator.

Comment: @Wolfie That's exactly, what I had in mind, but I wasn't sure, if that might've been already added to MATLAB.

Comment: You can [use `regexp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819094/3978545) for a one-liner if it's important

Answer (score 1):

Using `fileparts` or `regexp` would be easiest...

```
% mock data
files = {'a.txt', 'b.png', 'c.txt', 'd.txt.pdf'}; % note d is actually a .pdf file
target = '.txt';
```

The 3rd output of `fileparts` is the file extension, so

```
% option 1 - fileparts
[~,~,ext] = cellfun( @fileparts, files, 'uni', 0 );
files = files( strcmp( target, ext ) );
```

The `regexp` option is more robust than `strfind` because you can ensure the extension is at the end of the string

```
% option 2 - regexp ('$' to specify end of string)
files = files( ~cellfun( @isempty, regexp( files, [target, '$'], 'once' ) ) );
```